# Passing an array as a single argument to the MATLAB function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, arguments, version

I have some old Matlab code, which orginially ran on Matlab 2007.
I tried to run one on Matlab 2015b, however due to at least one update it crashes. For instance, I noticed the following in one of the functions:

```
function f_old(a,b)
    if ~exist('b','var'), b= 1; end;
```

Here, argument 'a' is a struct and its size can be 1x1 or 1x2. When it is 1x1, there is no problem and it works with both Matlab versions. However, when size(a) is 1x2 and argument 'b' is not passed to the function, newer Matlab believes that both 'a' (as 1x1) and 'b' are passed to the function, which was not intended originally in the older version.

I can easily solve this issue for this function by checking the size and etc.  but unfortunately there are so many related issues and I do not want to change the original code.

Is there maybe a 'flag' that may avoid this new behavior? Or does anyone know a practical way of forcing it to work as the older version.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide examples of calls to `f_old` ?

Comment: Can you provide examples that reproduce the problem? What you describe doesn't sounds right to me - I suspect b is being set elsewhere... Alternatively you could try `if nargin<2; b=1; end` where `nargin`gives the number of input arguments.

Comment: You may be unintentionally expanding the `struct` array in the call.  Are you either passing `a` while referencing a field like `f_old(a.field1)`?  This will expand `a` into two arguments.  To prevent this, wrap the argument in `[]`: `f_old([a.field1])`.

Comment: I don't have access to Matlab right now, but I think I am mistaken, this seems to happen in both Matlab versions. I'll give an example asap. I have already tried `if nargin<2; b=1;` but it still uses the 'a' struct and thinks that I passed 2 arguments to the function. However, I am only passing 'a', which has 2 fields with 1x2 size.